# QFT Literature recommendation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations

> Before answering, please see [**our policy**](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4698) on
>   resource recommendation questions. Please try to give substantial answers that detail the
>   **style, content, and prerequisites** of the book or paper (or other resource). Explain what the
>   resource is like as much as you can; that way the reader can decide which one is most suited
>   for them rather than blindly relying on the suggestions of others. Answers which just suggest a book
>   or paper will be deleted.
>
> And please, note that any answers to this are **community-owned**, which means that they are subject to  heavy editing, especially to make them comply with the book policy, to avoid deletion.

I am really getting confused. This term, I am sitting for a QFT 1 lecture and it is what I consider really hard for a physics student! But this is not my problem. My problem is that other than Weinberg, there is absolutely no QFT literature for a modern course.

Our literature recommendation for our course is first of all, Peskin and Schroeder. That is good, but not very detailed. The the other is Itzykson Zuber.

Another problem is that while our course is very excellent which also means that  the script is really good (you would  have to have listened to  very good lecture series on Quantum Mechanics (for the math).), to understand read "between the lines",  like representation theory, what is spin, etc., one needs to read Weinberg.

But the style of writing is very strenuous for me.

And thanks to a bad theoretical quantum mechanics lecture, I still really don't know what a spin is! I only know so far that this has something to do with a representation of the Lorentz algebra.

So, do you know some good resources or books which find a good way between the physics and the mathematics?

Comment: Is still ask myself why there are so much less good books in QFT?! I mean something like Weinberg but for a student with a lesser demand but still in a way precise. In electrodynamics or let's say mechanics there are plenty of good book...

Comment: Have you tried the QFT book in the demystified series? It isn't a real textbook, but at least having reading the same author's String Theory demystified, I suppose Quantum Field Theory Demystified would be very good as a supplement to a standard textbook.